POST buffer to file using libcurl in C++
upload.php:
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
  // if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>

I upload a file to the server as so:
$ curl http://127.0.0.1/upload.php -F "fileToUpload=@/home/user/file.txt"

I want to upload the buffer below to a file on the server. I do this with FTP, but in this case I want to be able to use SSL:
char *data = "this is the data to upload";

My code in my C++ program is below. I'm not sure how to structure the POSTFIELDS correctly. I see other threads on POST'ing, such as using this code:
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);

But they don't seem to be using any specific fields, or even using a PHP script.
Is there a way to do it without PHP?
Here is what I am using:
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1/upload.php");
/* Now specify the POST data */
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "fileToUpload=file.txt", data);


UPDATE:
I added the following but not able to upload the buffer into a file
  struct curl_slist *list = NULL;
    list = curl_slist_append(list, "multipart/form-data");
    // Then you pass that post to libcurl like this:
    curl_mime *form = curl_mime_init(curl);

    /* Fill in the file upload field */
    curl_mimepart *part = curl_mime_addpart(form);
    curl_mime_name(part, "fileToUpload");
    curl_mime_data(part, "file.txt", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);
    curl_mime_data(part, (char *)data, sizeof(data));
    // curl_mime_filedata(part, "photo.jpg");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, form);

I can upload a file by uncommenting to send photo.jpg but that is not my intention.

Your code is clean C, not C++.

Your PHP script is expecting an HTTP POST request with a multipart/form-data encoded payload.  Your curl command is sending that, but your C++ code is not. You can use CURLOPT_MIMEPOST for that purpose.  Provide it with a curl_mime object from curl_mime_init(), and add a curl_mimepart sub-object to it via curl_mime_addpart() which contains the data you want to send.
For example:
curl_mime *form = curl_mime_init(curl);

curl_mimepart *part = curl_mime_addpart(form);
curl_mime_name(part, "fileToUpload");
curl_mime_data(part, data, CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);
curl_mime_filename(part, "file.txt", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED); // optional
curl_slist *list = curl_slist_append(nullptr, "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
curl_mime_headers(part, list, 1);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, form);

// send the request, then...

curl_mime_free(form);

If you want to use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, you have to format the entire MIME data yourself (see RFC 7578), but CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS sets the HTTP Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded by default, which you would have to override by using CUROPT_HTTPHEADER to specify multipart/form-data instead.
For example:
curl_slist *list = curl_slist_append(nullptr, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);

std::string postData =
    "--AaB03x\r\n"
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload\"; filename=\"file.txt\"\r\n"
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    + std::string(data) + 
    "\r\n--AaB03x--\r\n";

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postData.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, static_cast<long>(postData.size()));
// or:
// curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, static_cast<curl_off_t>(postData.size()));


On a side note:

I want to upload the buffer below to a file on the server. I do this with FTP, but in this case I want to be able to use SSL

FTP is able to use SSL/TLS.

can you be more specific about how I can actually upload the buffer as the file on the server? I have tried using the mime right now and only able to upload an actual file from the same directory. i tried using data but it won't upload. Where do I put the filename to be saved on the server? I modified my answer to include what I changed

There are examples in the docs I linked to, did you not read them? The example on curl_mime_init() shows how to post a data string in a MIME part. You can use curl_mime_filename() to specify a filename for the data. As for your MIME code, there are some mistakes, such as not using CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER correctly (and you don't need it with CURLOPT_MIMEPOST), and needing strlen(data) (or CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED) instead of sizeof(data) since data is a char* pointer.

ok you aren't understanding what I am trying to do. I don't want to upload a file. I can do that by using CreateProcess on curl command. I want to upload a buffer AS a file. Meaning I want to generate a new file out of a buffer. I figured the strlen part out, that is out of habit that I usually use char buffer[] more than pointers, fixed that instantly.
